# PHP code submitting to MySQL isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been tying to figure out what is wrong for a long time, but I cannot figure it out. I have been trying to connect to a local MySQL database. When I run this, no error is thrown. Also, I know that the database and the table exist, and I know that my username and password are correct.

```
<?php 
// Connects to your Database 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "**MY_USERNAME**", "**MY_PASSWORD**", "gamesite_data") or die(mysql_error()); 
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ($username, $password, $firstname, $last_name, $age);"
);
?> 
<?php
mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Please, before you do anything else, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). `mysqli` supports SQL placeholders that make SQL injection bugs almost impossible if used correctly.

Comment: debug your code, start with having the SQL-INSERT-command as $sql and var_dump $sql. Then go to your phpmyadmin and use that SQL-Command on your Database and see the error-message. And: Enable error-messages in PHP!

Comment: You're using `mysql_error()` after your `mysqli_connect` and there's no closing tags in `mysqli_close($con)`. Maybe thats the problem ?

Comment: Your values need quotes around each one

Answer (score 0):

If the values of username, password, first_name, last_name are strings, you have to surround them with single quotes here:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$firstname."', '".$last_name."', ".$age.")");
```

And if you use `mysqli_connect`, you have to use also `mysqli_error` instead of `mysql_error`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 $con = new mysqli("localhost", "**MY_USERNAME**", "**MY_PASSWORD**", "gamesite_data") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
 $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
 $age = $_POST["age"];

 $query="INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$firstname', '$last_name', '$age')";
 $con->query($query);
 $con->close();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ($username, $password, $firstname, $last_name, $age);"
);
```

Should be

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $age);"
);
```

You dont have `$firstname` variable, you have `$first_name`

Also keep in ming that you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for all `$_POST` values.

And i think is a good practice to pass variable into query as strings :

```
"INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `age`) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$age');"
```

Answer (score 0):

i noticed your code here you made 2 mistake first one is you take wrong variable name into your sql query .you are declare $first_name variable but you are taking $firstname and second one you are taking extra semicolon (;) just after your value's end.

please use this code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gamesite_data");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$query = "INSERT INTO information (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`,  `age`) VALUES ($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $age)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
```

hope its worked